# Navigate to parent activity in java code in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-manifest, android-navigation

I have created a adapterview along with bottomnavigation view in my code.
This is the parent activity i have used for all my naviagtion views

```
<activity android:name=".activity.patient.painpoint.PainPointBackView"
           android:parentActivityName=".activity.patient.assessment.PatientAssessmentActivity" />
```

This is the adapter view which i have given as parentActivity for all the tabs

[![adapter view][1]][1]

This is one of the tab which i used,

[![tab view][2]][2]

How to navigate to the parent activity i.e, Adapter view when i clicked "assessment" icon from tab view. If i use onbackpressed()  it is taking to the another tab. I dont need to call using intent since it is a adapter i need to pass all the values again. Is there any way calling Parent activity from java code(PatientAssessmentActivity.class) and if i press toolbar back button it is navigating to parent activity. i need this to happen when i click assessment tab icon.

This is the code i have used,

```
private void setupNavigationView() {
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        assessment = realm.where(Assessment.class).equalTo("patient_id", patientID).findFirst();
        Log.v(Constants.TAG, "addsdsds " + assessment);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_assessment:
                    **here i need to navigate to parent activity**
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_front:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PainPointBackView.this, PainPointFrontView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("patient_id", assessment.getPatient_id());
                        intent.putExtra("assessment_id", assessment.getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_back:
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_left:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(PainPointBackView.this, PainPointLeftView.class);
                        intent2.putExtra("patient_id", assessment.getPatient_id());
                        intent2.putExtra("assessment_id", assessment.getId());
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_right:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(PainPointBackView.this, PainPointRightView.class);
                        intent3.putExtra("patient_id", assessment.getPatient_id());
                        intent3.putExtra("assessment_id", assessment.getId());
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PatientAssessmentActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

As per Android Doc,

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP If set, and the activity being launched is
>   already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
>   will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
>   old activity as a new Intent

Refer : [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Same issue bro, going to activity but i am not able to see adapter view

Comment: which activity has adpterview? Isn't it in PatientAssessmentActivity?

Comment: yes adapterview is in PatientAssessmentActivity, I am getting the view before setting the adapter i.e, "No results found"